# What does the phrase "a monk's game" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard this in a podcast from The Economist magazine. I can find a few usages online, but no definitions. Maybe I am spelling it wrong. Is it monk, or is it another word that sounds like monk?

The context was: "Predicting the price of oil is a monk's game."

Comment: A mug's game? But the pronunciation is not very close. I subscribe to the Economist podcast and can you let me know the date of the broadcast?

Comment: I've just listed to it and it is indeed **a mug's game**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've likely misheard "a mug's game"; says the [CBC](https://www.facebook.com/cbcnews/posts/10153069303694604?comment_id=10153069306469604&offset=0&total_comments=57):

> Predicting the price of oil is *a mug's game*, but Alberta has managed to quantify the many billions that have evaporated for this year, next year and the year after that.

A mug is a fool, one easily duped.  Partridge's *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* cites its use from 1857.  So anyone who bets on the future price of oil is likely to lose.